# JQuery write specific count of elements from remote page

Tags: jquery, select, count, element

The following is being used to write all `img.cover` elements from and external page (within domain) to `div`. I need to control the number of elements written by selecting or writing one by the first 6, or 8, or etc. as designated inside the function.

Please advise if you can see a simple way to do so. I am new to JQuery and this is as far as I get.

```
function loadClass(targetElement, sourceClass) {
    var mytarget = $(targetElement); // cache the initial
    mytarget.hide().empty();
    mytarget.load("[root URL removed]/0_gallery_covers.html ." + sourceClass);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        mytarget.show();
    });
}
```

Comment: I struggle to see anything related to "count of elements" in your code here.  Can you elaborate on the question a bit more perhaps - explain in more details your objective.  Also that `html ." + sourceClass` fragment appears to create an invalid URL here with that period followed by whatever is in that object.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
        mytarget.show();
});` probably only needs to be `mytarget.show();` since that event looks to have already executed if the function runs.

Comment: Mark: Sorry... I left out the "show" part, so my mistake caused some confusion; don't know how to edit the original post. At present, the function would retrieve / return / write all "img.cover" elements to the target element (a preview of covers in and ebook gallery). I want to display a small subset of the most recent covers in another area of my site. Does that clarify enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling on this one is that you would use the [page fragments load](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) method but include the 'sourceClass' you mentioned as well as a limit based on the [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector.

Your load may be along the lines of:

```
mytarget.load("[root URL removed]/0_gallery_covers.html ." + sourceClass+":lt(8)");
```

You should be able to tailor the :lt() expression for the amount of content you want.

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0e5b9qgn/) [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for a simple test using only local data.

Comment: Prefect, Dave!  Thanks so much. Didn't know what I was looking for when I tried to search it out myself. Here is the final function for reference.
    function loadClass(targetElement, sourceClass) {
        var mytarget = $(targetElement);
        mytarget.hide().empty();
        mytarget.load("[root URL]/0_gallery_covers.html ." + sourceClass +":lt(8)");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            mytarget.show();
        });
    }

Comment: Glad I could help - if this meets requirement and solves the issue - please accept the answer.

Comment: Got it... sorry I missed that. Still getting used to some methods around here.  --J.C.